# How do you know poly count or how many triangles are there in your mesh or object?

Tags: polycount

How can you know your poly count? I searched online, & all the answers are for versions from years ago. How can you see the number of triangles you have in Blender 2.83?

Answer (score 1):

Shoot, I just found out on another post.
The post was indirectly related to my question, but didn't answer it directly, however, I found out it actually answered my question in the details it provided.

The poly count is shown in the bottom right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the lower right corner u can see the no. of triangles. No. of faces and no. of vertices.